# How to get Region text from address id (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, customer-address, address, regions

I am not able to get region text from address id,

```
 <?php $_pAddsses = $block->getDefaultBilling() ?>
 <?php echo $block->getAddressById($_pAddsses)->getRegionId() ?>      
  // output 5



 <?php echo $block->getAddressById($_pAddsses)->getRegion() ?>
   //output ""(empty)
```

And for my question, I don't have any region code, as many countries don't have region dropdown, like - India country dropdown doesn't have region dropdown, so in the database, the region id is 0 and region is whatever we filled in the text box for the region.

[image]

I checked the database it does contain region text.

I need region text to populate the region text box for which `region dropdown` is not available for countries.

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following code to get the region from the address id.

```
$address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
$address->getRegion()->getRegion();
```

where `$this->addressRepository` is the object of `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface`
`$address->getRegion()` will give return you the object of `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface`
and then calling `getRegion()` on it will give you string.

Comment: I am not able to print the return value $address->getRegion(); Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region could not be converted to string

Comment: i did this  
<?php $regionName = $orderHelper->getRegionName($_pAddsses) ?>
<?php echo "region " .$regionName ?>

Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region could not be converted to string

Comment: Try $address->getRegion()->getRegion();
I have updated the same in my answer as well.

Comment: why two time getRegion()

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks , magento will always be a mystery for me

Comment: @summu It is simple, just check the classes which I have used and you will able to understand. When I am calling $address->getRegion() means I am calling getRegion method of interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface which will give me the object of Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface. Now this returned interface also has the method getRegion, 2nd time I am calling the getRegion of Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface which will give me the region string.

Answer (score 1):

In Block File :-

```
protected $AddressRepoInterface;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $AddressRepoInterface

){
    $this->AddressRepoInterface = $AddressRepoInterface;
}
public function getRegionName() {
    return $this->AddressRepoInterface->getById($addressId)->getRegion();
}
```

In phtml File :-

```
$block->getRegionName();
```

Comment: I am getting this error Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address::getRegionName()

Comment: This is my block file \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: from where do I get $regionId

Comment: And for my question, i dont have any region code, as many countries doesnt have region dropdown, like - India country dropdown doesnt have region dropdown, so in database region code is 0 and region is whatever we filled in text box for region

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: check my updated answer