# magento 2.4 save region as string in address

Tags: magento2, customer-address, regions

I'm importing my customers via code and part of that import involves addresses and regions. If the region is in the database, I have no issue in importing it, I simply get the region id by the region interface:

```
/** @var \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $region */
$region = $this->regionFactory->create()->loadByName($regionName, $countryId);
$regionId = $region->getRegionId();
```

This works. However, most of my customers have no regionId in the database.

On backend/frontend, when there is no region entry in the database, customers can fill in a text input and the region name is saved in the address. I'd like to accomplish the same thing with my code, that is: I'd like to save the region name even if there is no database entry.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264250/how-to-get-region-text-from-address-id-magento-2

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need to retrieve the region by the database, that I'm already doing. I need to save the region name in the address when it's not associated to a database entry. In the frontend/backend I do this when I fill in the region input text field instead of using the dropdown. I don't know how to that via code because if I use the region name (string) with $address->setRegion($regionStringName) it gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know and do give a like if you need more info.

- To save region name in the database using customer id , please follow below.
- Prepare a module to stimulate this functionality of code to execute on whatever basis you like , i assume you already have a module ,let me show you via a custom script  which will be placed in the magento root directory.
- Please look at this table , where the customer address gets saved , in this table there are two columns which we should consider

> customer_address_entity

> column = region_id when there is region_id , enter this column

> column = region , when there is only region name , enter this column

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

setRegionName($objectManager);

function setRegionName($objectManager)
{
    $customerIds = ["1"];
    foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
        try {
            /** @var Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $customerAddressRepo */
            $customerAddressRepo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface');
            $customerAddress = $customerAddressRepo->getById($customerId);
            /** @var Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface $regionInterface */
            $regionInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface');
            $region = "Chennai";
            $regionInterface->setRegion($region);
            $customerAddress->setRegion($regionInterface);
            $customerAddressRepo->save($customerAddress);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you a lot! It is weird, though, that the factory of the region is in a module (magento\directory) whille the interface is in another (magento\customer). I expect that the customerRegionInteface would be associated with a customerRegionRepository just like the customer AddressRepositoryInterface is associated with the customer AddressInterfaceFactory, but I looked at the customer module and didnt found anything regarding region factory.